# Can Gluu be installed on Shared hosting?

Tags: single-sign-on, shared-hosting

I am searching for an open source SSO software that I can self host and came across Gluu. Can Gluu be installed on a shared hosting such as Hostgator/Bluhost or godaddy ? *(these hosting names are just examples)*

Comment: I believe this is something that you need to ask with them. But, if this is shared hosting, you don't have much flexibility to install your own software.

Comment: I will do. Our shared hosting has a lot of software but nothing for SSO.

Comment: I believe you can't install it on their shared hosting plan. You may need to purchase dedicated server.

Comment: Our shared hosting company was blunt. They do not have such thing at all. I agree with you that a dedicated server would do the trick, but requires some budgeting before getting it up and running on the cloud. Also it will have to be a cloud server with a fix monthly rate rather than metered. I will update this post if I find anything interesting.